# Is it possible to get a value with a formulafield fro product to Order Product

Tags: formula, externalid, order

I have a external id value on product which I want to put on the Order Product object. Is this possible with a formula field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access it through PriceBookEntry.

```
PricebookEntry.Product2.YourField
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing thought I had to acces trough product directly

Comment: @Thomas Most Welcome!